# Birt, getting value from render to report

Tags: grails, render, birt

I have a grails app and I am using birt plugin 4.3.0.3., I want to dinamicaly hide chart or table in BirtReportService.render method.

First I tried to change HideRules, I get the hide rules and I put in my own, but render task ignores the new rules.

Now I am trying to make javascript function (expression builder) to set hide, but I can not get any value, variable, parameter from render to it.

Any ideas, how to access value from render in expression builder (Property Editor>Properties>Visibility tab) and use it to hide an element.
Or any other way to do it (In run I do not know if I am hidding an element, that would be too easy :S)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your rptdesign file should have a dataset. When do you want to hide this element? You can do something like this:

var showField = false;
if(datasetrow["field"] == "someValue") {
showField = true;
}
showField;

Comment: It is not dependant on values in dataset, it is dependant on what user clicks in my grails app. It should give him three posibilities export all, chart or table. I allready have the rptdocument at that time, so only presentation(and its methods) is avalible.

Comment: Ahh I see, then you could do something like this in the visibility tab for the chart: 
var hideChart = false;
if(params["your_grails_param"].value == 'showOnlyTable') {
 hideChart = true;
}
hideChart

Comment: Even with parameter, its value can not be set in render part. You can get to it through report context, but setting its value does not take. Plus I would like to avoid parameter (I have 80+ reports). Your solution works, because prarameter gets its value in run, but I want to set it in render. Thanks for looking at this.